# How can you approx. the max. size of the Coulomb repulsion force between alpha particle and a gold atom for both the plum model and Rutherford model?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, atomic-physics, scattering, coulombs-law

How to approximate the maximum size of the Coulomb repulsion force between an alpha particle and a gold atom/nucleus for both the plum pudding model and the Rutherford model*

Please could someone explain how to work this out?

Comment: I do not know how you are going to do it for the plum pudding model but for the Rutherford model, I am sure you also need the input speed.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the plum pudding "model" was not really much of a model. As in, there was little playing with it to see what it implied. But, if the positive charge of the nucleus is spread out widely one would not see a strong central force scattering, which is what Geiger and Marsden observed, and Rutherford modeled.

Comment: Pudding model=mostly neutral at "large'' scale. If your charge distribution can be seen by a fast enough projectile (energy is inverse to length, so customarily, and somewhat brutally, more energy=more spatial resolution), good luck on integrating over that distribution